# generate a hierarchical markdown list whose elements are links to files in my git repository?

Tags: git, sed, find, markdown

I am trying to create a git hook which generates a `readme.md` file that contains an "index" in which only the .c files, as part of my class assignments, are linked. The directory tree looks like this

```
$ tree
├── assignment1
│   ├── linear_lists.c
|   |── circular_lists.c
|   |── main.c
├── assignment2
│   ├── stacks.c
│   ├── main.c
| ...
└── readme.md
```

So far I have only figured out how to generate the code for a single leveled list

```
* [assignment1/linear_lists.c](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/me/myrepo/main/assignment1/linear_lists.c)
* [assignment1/circular_lists.c](/https://raw.githubusercontent.com/me/myrepo/main/assignment1/circular_lists.c)
...
* [assignment2/stacks.c](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/me/myrepo/assignment2/stacks.c)
...
```

using :

```
find . -name "*.c" | sed "s|^\./\(.*\)|* \[\1\]($url/$repo/$branch/\1)|" >> readme.md
```

I want to represent the above as a two-level markdown list by basically generating the following code (using only Unix utilties if possible)

```
* assignment1 <!-- name of parent -->
    + [linear_lists.c](same link as above)
    + [circular_lists.c](same link as above)
...
* assignment2
    + [stacks.c](same link as above)
...
```

Is this possible ? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an awk script to convert `find` output to a Markdown
list of lists with links.

Use as:

```shell
find DIR -type f \( -name '*.[ch]' -o -name '*.cpp' \) |
sort -t '/' -k 1 -k 2 |
awk -v base=BASE -f path/to/script
```

where

- DIR is . or dirname, for a compact result avoid '/'s
- the sort step is optional
- BASE is a path prefix, e.g. 'https://example.org/pub/'

```awk
BEGIN {
    FS = "/"
    levelindent = 4
    split("*+-*+-*+-*+-*+-*+-",liststyle,//)
}
{
    sub(/^\.\//,"",$0)
    depth = NF-1
    filename = $(NF)
    path = $0; sub(/[^/]*$/,"",path)

    ## print each path part on first dir entry
    accpath = ""
    for ( d = 1; d <= depth; d++ ) {
        accpath = accpath $(d) "/"
        if ( ! seen[accpath]++ )
            printf("%*s %s %s\n", levelindent*(d-1), "", \
                liststyle[d], $(d) "/")
    }

    printf("%*s %s [%s](%s)\n", levelindent*(depth), "", \
        liststyle[depth+1], filename, base path filename)
}
```

Each pathname (`$0`) is stripped of any leading `./` and split
by `/` as field separator (`FS`) using the number of fields (`NF`)
to determine directory depth (`NF-1`), and filename (`$(NF)`).
A path is made by stripping off the filename.

Each dir in path (`$1` through `$(NF-1)`) - on first encounter only -
and filename is output
as a Markdown list item, each leaf node as a Markdown link
concatenating base (from command line), path, and filename.

Indentation is handled using the `printf` width flag (the `*` in `%*s`)
to output a space-filled field of specified width, varying with the
directory depth.

**EDIT**: support for file-less dirs, added explanation

Output:

```
 * week/
     + assignment1/
         - [linear_lists.c](/pub/week/assignment1/linear_lists.c)
         - [main.c](/pub/week/assignment1/main.c)
         - supp/
             * [supp.c](/pub/week/assignment1/supp/supp.c)
             * extra/
                 + [extra.h](/pub/week/assignment1/supp/extra/extra.h)
                 + [extra.c](/pub/week/assignment1/supp/extra/extra.c)
         - [circular_lists.c](/pub/week/assignment1/circular_lists.c)
     + assignment2/
         - [stacks.c](/pub/week/assignment2/stacks.c)
         - [stacks.h](/pub/week/assignment2/stacks.h)
         - [main.c](/pub/week/assignment2/main.c)
         - extra/
             * [extra.c](/pub/week/assignment2/extra/extra.c)
```

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

prefix="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/me/myrepo/main"
for d in */; do                 # find directories in the current directory
    d=${d%/}                    # remove a trailing slash
    printf "* %s\n" "$d"        # print the name of parent
    for f in "$d"/*; do         # find files in each directory
        f=${f#*/}               # remove dirname to extract the filename
        printf "    + [%s](%s)\n" "$f" "$prefix/$d/$f"
                                # print tha name of child and the link
    done
done > readme.md
```

Generated `readme.md`:

```
* assignment1
    + [circular_lists.c](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/me/myrepo/main/assignment1/circular_lists.c)
    + [linear_lists.c](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/me/myrepo/main/assignment1/linear_lists.c)
    + [main.c](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/me/myrepo/main/assignment1/main.c)
* assignment2
    + [main.c](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/me/myrepo/main/assignment2/main.c)
    + [stacks.c](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/me/myrepo/main/assignment2/stacks.c)
```

Please note the script above is specialized for the two-level directory tree. If we need more levels, we need to modify the script.